# shouldn't $cacheFactory#get() return copy of cached object instead of a reference?

Tags: angularjs, cachefactory

I encountered a situation that I was not expecting while using `$cacheFactory`, shouldn't objects stored in cache be unaffected by changes made outside of `$cacheFactory`, means object returned from cache using $cacheFactory.get() should not reflect changes back to the current cached object.

I have a demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/vladimir_ze/s9twdbup/

Answer (score 0):

```
// get model from cache and modify it
$scope.modelFromCache = cache.get('model');
$scope.modelFromCache.author.name = 'Bob';

// Telling you're right and instead of copy you get a reference
console.log($scope.modelFromCache === cache.get('model')); // true

$scope.anotherModelFromCache = angular.copy(cache.get('model')); 

// Solution if you just want a copy of cache property data
console.log($scope.anotherModelFromCache === cache.get('model')); // false
```

I think you're right and that behaviour should be made clear because

> Retrieves named data stored in the Cache object.

is kind of misleading...

Ref. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$cacheFactory.Cache

Good catch btw :)